# Maven only include some classes

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have multiple classes in my project, but for a specific jar I don't want to put all classes into the jar.

```
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>THRechner-test</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>my.koque.threchner.Einheiten</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Then I run the following command: `mvn clean package -Ptest`, but the class is not put into the jar. Running the command without the include lines does put all files into the jar.

How can I just include one class into the jar?

Comment: First what is the specific reason? and in general if you like to make separate JAR make separate modules which means to create a multi module build which solves the problem very easy without the need of profiles and manually activating them etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure the jar plugin like this :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>                      
                    <include>**/Einheiten.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: HI @devskillup couldn't they have just done this too?                         <include>my.koque.threchner.Einheiten.class</include>  (i.e. add .class?)

Comment: no, but you can use this : <include>my/koque/threchner/Einheiten.class</include>